# How to predict index size?

Tags: mysql, index-tuning, mysql-5.7

I have a table with ~100M records of unique urls `VARCHAR(1023)` like `/t/some_page_name_...`, an average length is 51 chars.

I'm trying to select the best way to apply a unique index on the table, so I need to calculate by which column unique index will have the smallest size:

```
VARCHAR(1023) (url) - data size ~52 bytes, index size - ??? bytes
VARCHAR(64) (SHA2(url, 256)) - data size - 65 bytes, index size - ??? bytes
BINARY(32) (UNHEX(SHA2(url, 256))) - data size - 32 bytes, index size - ??? bytes
```

Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: at least keep in mind - any conversion stop using indexes for search, for example for left LIKE - LIKE '/t/some_page_name%' it will work only with 1st case

Comment: Why predict and not test?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ how it can be tested? `mysql.innodb_index_stats` returns value with +/- 50% accuracy - I created 5 tables with the same data (70M records) and got different stats by `PRIMARY KEY (id)` index: 4.74Gb, 5.8Gb, 7.9Gb, 10.1Gb, 10.1Gb. P.S.: I run `optimize table ...`

Comment: @Alexey - why not create this tables and check size on disk before and after create index?

Answer (score 1):

First approximation:  An InnoDB table or index will be 2-3 times as large as you would expect from adding up the column sizes.

I get 53 for `VARCHAR(1023)` with an average of 51 characters.  `VARCHAR` for non-small max needs 2 bytes for length.  This also assumes there are no non-English letters in the url.  For example, each Chinese *character* takes 3-4 *bytes*.  The index size needs to be computed in *bytes*.

For your 3 examples, there won't be a lot of difference, since most of the 2x-3x comes from BTree overhead, padding, row overhead, etc.

Another thing that can make a significant difference in index size is whether the rows are are inserted in sorted order -- or not.  That leads to well packed BTree blocks -- or not.

Also, your numbers are incomplete.  Three different cases:  MyISAM index, InnoDB PRIMARY KEY, InnoDB secondary key.

For InnoDB secondary key, the `PRIMARY KEY` is tacked on.  So, you need to add whatever sized those column(s) are.  Typical case: 4 bytes for `INT`.

Even if you get past all that, there will be anomalies.  A 1-row table will have 16KB for each secondary index.  At a certain table size, the "allocation unit" switches from 16KB to 4MB.  After that, adding a row will rarely change the index size, but sometimes will show a big jump.

Etc, etc.

An aside...  Indexes using `SHA2` (or other digests/hashes) are notoriously bad for performance on huge tables.  They lead to random accesses, which blows out cache, which leads to reads and writes being I/O bound, which is deadly for *huge* tables.